# set utf8 in database - can I remove SET NAMES utf8 from php code

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have set utf8 in mysql database

now it shows

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+


+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
```

I have the below in the php code

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

and

```
$database = mysqli_connect('host','user','pass','database');
mysqli_query($database,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Since I set utf8 in database, can I remove `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'")` and `mysqli_query($database,"SET NAMES 'utf8'")` from the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mysqli_set_charset

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Change character set to utf8
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid setting utf8 in the code. So, can I remove mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'") and mysqli_query($database,"SET NAMES 'utf8'") from the php code (I have utf8 set in the database)?

Comment: you can remove "SET NAMES 'utf8'" but need to use mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");  so that you will get the right data from the query and the data can be parsed after.

Comment: You mean to say, I need to use mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8"); even if I have uft8 set in the database (as shown in my question)?

Comment: yes because php does not know what encoding technique to use.

Comment: instead of adding mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8") in the code, can I set default_charset = "UTF-8" in php.ini?